# Missing image when running shiny example from tutorial

Tags: r, shiny

I am rather new in shiny, so I was running through some tutorials. However, I have a problem loading images from a file inside the "www" folder of the shiny app.

For example, when I run the code below, I get a missing image. However, if I refer to an image online, e.g., if I substitute "bigorb.png" by "http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson2/www/bigorb.png", I get the desired image without problems. I am using R version 3.3.1 on Windows 10. Can anyone help me?

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      img(src="bigorb.png", height = 400, width = 400)
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you can also add the link: `img(src="http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson2/www/bigorb.png", height = 400, width = 400)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did add that link and it works, but I would like it to work also with an image somewhere in my computer, not online...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. Create folder /myApp
2. Inside /myApp: create a file `starter.R` with the following code, and make sure to set the working directory correctly:

   ```
   library(shiny)
   setwd("PATH_TO_myApp")
   shiny::runApp("app")
   ```
3. In the folder /myApp, create a subfolder /app.
4. In /myApp/app/: create file "app.R" with your code from above.
5. Create another sub-subfolder /myApp/app/www/ . Include your image file.
6. Execute `starter.R`.

So your file list is:

```
    /myApp/starter.R
    /myApp/app/app.R
    /myApp/app/www/bigorb.png
```